# SCILAB-animation, scale constantly changing

Tags: scilab

```
 F=zeros(3,3);
F(1,:)=[0.3,0.35,0.2];
T=diag([0.2,0.5],-1);
P=(F+T)
X=[100;100;57]


    plot2d([1,2,3],X)
    for i=1:100
            drawlater();
            X=P*X;
            clf;
            plot2d([1,2,3],X)
            drawnow();
        end
```

scilab is constantly rescaling my animation. How to avoid rescaling ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to set the "data_bounds" as it was already given in another answer, you might have to set "tight_limits" to "on".

If tight_limits is "off", then the axis limits are not necessarily set to the values specified by data_bounds but may be set to a slightly larger range in order to achieve pretty tic labels.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `clf()`, current figure is cleared, therefore, there are no data boundaries set when `plot2d()` is called. So for every pair `clf() plot()` new boundaries are set, and the graph is re-scaled.

If you need the figure to be clear, and fixed boundaries, you have to set that axes property `data_bound` using `set()` in each loop:

```
set(gca(), 'data_bound', [x_min, y_min; x_max, y_max]);
```

I noticed your animation goes from 1 to 3 in X, and from 0 to 100 in Y, so you could write your loop like this:

```
plot2d([1,2,3],X)
for i=1:100
    drawlater();
    X=P*X;
    clf();
    plot2d([1,2,3],X)
    set(gca(), 'data_bounds', [1, 0; 3 100]);
    drawnow();
end
```

I also noticed the result is not good, but that's a problem with the data you're generating and the fixed scale you want, and not the animation "technique" itself.

Comment: Since the data converges to 0+ strictly, you may use a logarithmic axe     

    `plot2d([1,2,3],X);
    set(gca(),'log_flags','nl');
    set(gca(), 'data_bounds', [1, 1e-30; 3 100]);`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this way of doing the animation, i.e. by using the `data` field of `Polyline` entity:

```
clf
plot2d([1,2,3],X)
h = gce().children
gca().data_bounds(3:4)=[1e-30,100];
gca().log_flags="nln"

for i=1:100
    X=P*X;
    h.data(:,2) = X;
    sleep(100)
end
```

Without the `sleep(100)` the animation is too fast...